# What is the purpose of XMLNAMESPACES in a CTE query on the SSRS database?

Tags: sql-server, xml, reporting-services

I'm writing some queries against the SSRS ReportServer database.  I know the Catalog.Content field contains the report RDL/XML in binary format and you need to convert it to VARBINARY to read it.  My question is about the use of XMLNAMESPACES.  Most of the example queries I've found use this, however the query works just fine without it.  I'm trying to understand why XMLNAMESPACES is needed in this type of query.  Here's a query I found (and slightly modified) that returns the same results with and without it. Thanks for helping me understand why I need to use XMLNAMESPACES.

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner' AS rd ),
CTE_RDL AS (
  SELECT C.[Name]
        ,C.ItemID
        ,C.[Path]
        ,CASE WHEN C.[Type] NOT IN (1,3,11) THEN
              CASE WHEN LEFT(CONVERT(varbinary(max),C.Content),3) = 0xEFBBBF THEN CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varbinary(max),C.Content),4,LEN(CONVERT(varbinary(max),C.Content)))))
                   ELSE CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(varbinary(max),C.Content))
              END 
              ELSE NULL
         END AS [ContentXML]
    FROM [ReportServer].dbo.[Catalog] C
   WHERE C.[Type] = 2
)
SELECT R.[Name]
      ,R.[Path]
      ,R.ItemID
      ,DS.value('.','VARCHAR(100)') AS [RDL_DATASOURCE_NAME]
      ,CS.value('.','VARCHAR(100)') AS [RDL_CONNECTSTRING]
      ,CASE WHEN CS.value('.','VARCHAR(100)') IS NULL THEN 'SHARED' ELSE 'EMBEDDED' END AS [RDL_DATASOURCE_TYPE]
  FROM CTE_RDL R
       OUTER APPLY R.ContentXML.nodes('//*:DataSource/@Name') AS D(DS)
       OUTER APPLY R.ContentXML.nodes('//*:ConnectString')    AS C(CS)
 ORDER BY R.[Name]
```

Comment: `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` isn't a CTE. A CTE is declared as `[WITH] {CTE Name} AS` (note the `AS` afterwards). `XMLNAMESPACES` is a different "thing", specifically for `xml`. See [WITH XMLNAMESPACES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/with-xmlnamespaces?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: It's used to define the XML namespaces (and especially prefixes) used in the XML functions like `.Nodes()` and `.Value()`, though it's mostly irrelevant for the posted code because that uses namespace wildcards, e.g.: `*:DataSource` and `*:ConnectString`.

Comment: Ah.  I was reading up on using XMLNAMESPACES for creating XML and that made sense.  This code was confusing me but now I get it.  Thanks very much to both of you!

Comment: @Charlieface It helps, I need to play with that some to understand better, I'm still new to querying xml.  Thanks much!

Comment: You should have a button to accept this duplicate and close the question